# Is there an equivalent of AddDllDirectory in Linux and Mac?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, macos, shared-libraries

I have a folder where many Shared Libraries are in. I want to load all of them in my program so iterate them and load them but some got not loaded because it could not find a dependency which lies in the same folder but (at least in windows) it doesn't search the same folder.
I googled and found 'AddDllDirectory' for windows.

Is there a equivalent for this function in Linux and Mac?
If not how could I workaround this problem?

It needs to be runtime because the folder containing the Shared Libraries can change.

Answer (score 0):

For a single, specific program, execute it from the shell (or with a script) like this:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path:to:libraries /path/to/program
```

To set up system wide libraries, adjust the contents of `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` or `/etc/ld.so.conf`.

If you just want to make your programs refer to a specific additional path, have a look at the `rpath` linker flags. E.g.

```
gcc -o my_program -Wl,-rpath='additional/library/paths'
```

With rpath take note about the special "variable" `${ORIGIN}` which allows you to specify paths relative to the install location of the linked binary. For details read the manual page of ld.so